# Entering text to span Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, key, send

I try to enter text to span in place of "SAMPLE TEXT". I'm using Selenium/Python but I can't do it using send_keys method. Do you have any other ideas how can I do that?
I attached screenshots with HTML and screenshot from app

[image]

[image]

I tried to use that code, but doesnt work:

```html
body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="oss-view-wrapper"]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/pre/span')
body.send_keys("TEST")
```

Comment: Please show some code first. Also the link to the page you are scraping.

Comment: try this xpath and let me know `//div[@class='CodeMirror-code']/div/pre/span[@role='presentation']`

Comment: uh...what were you expecting to happen?  I don't think that you can enter text into a 'span' element.  You'd need a textarea or input element.  So, unless there's some special Javascript involved here to handle text input to that element, I don't believe that send_keys() will do anything.  Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use javasecriptExceutor for that, Please chech code at once i am not have deep knowledge of Python:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('Your xpath')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'test'", element)
```

Comment: I am facing similar type of situation. I am developing a script to automate a tool where i need to enter pricing related information. code is <span><div class="cell-border"></div></span>. I am able to click on this element using javascript but not able to enter text. I have tried above way but script is entering text and immediately text disaapear. Please help if u can