# ElementNotInteractableException using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
#wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://rentry.co/wftw8/edit")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea").send_keys("hello")
time.sleep(3)  
driver.find_element_by_id("id_edit_code").send_keys("iRfiNq6M")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Save")).click()
driver.close()
```

This error is shown while running the above code in google colab.

**ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)**

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I edited the answer because it was wrong, so I dig a little more and
discover that the tag `textarea` is not which is really canging the value of the `textarea`, instead is the **innerText** inside a span element. To change that innerText you need to select the **span**
and call **execute_script**, let's better show you how to do it:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# note I commented this to see 
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
# chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
# chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://rentry.co/wftw8/edit")
try:

    # here I selected the **span** element that I talk above
    span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text"]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre/span')
    # change the innerText thwough js
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innnerText="Hello Lola"', span)
    # just wait for the id_edit_code to be present
    edit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_edit_code")))
    edit.send_keys("hjhkjhjh")
    # and same as you had it
    driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

finally:
    driver.close()
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136239/entering-text-to-span-selenium-python) was of great help.

Comment: Try hashing the line driver.findElement(By.linkText("Save")).click() ,then also the error is same

Comment: Could you try to comment all this ```time.sleep(3)  
driver.find_element_by_id("id_edit_code").send_keys("iRfiNq6M")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Save")).click()
driver.close()``` and tell me what happend??

Comment: Because maybe you need to tell selenium to wait for the element to be present like [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: So the problem, seems to be that you are not waiting for the element to be present. Take a look at the link that I passed you above. I don't have the chrome driver so I cannot test your code :(

Comment: What kind of changes ?

Comment: I edited the question, and tested the code. Wroks fine now

Answer (score 0):

It goes into an edit screen after. Here's a more stable way instead of using time.sleep. You can also start handling exceptions this way.

```
driver.get("https://rentry.co/wftw8/edit")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    #wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "textarea"))).send_keys("hello")
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id_edit_code"))).send_keys("iRfiNq6M")
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submitButton"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Edit']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Save']"))).click()
    print('done')
except:
    print('error')
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```